# Algebraic characterization of first order "operations" using limit ultrapowers

Tags: logic, model-theory

In his review http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.bams/1183537899 of the Chang and Keisler's classic book "Model Theory,"  M. Makkai writes:  "… let us note that it is possible to formulate the results in 6.4 in a way (that the reviewer learned from A. Joyal) that brings them neatly in line with the idea of algebraic characterization of first order "operations"". My question is what could such a possible a way to reformulate the results of 6.4 be?

Comment: It might help if you state the result 6.4 here.